# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/Session;

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

I am following the quick start app for Android  ( https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/android/quickstart ) and is giving the following error:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.google.identitytoolkit.demo, PID: 12813
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/facebook/Session;
 (...)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.facebook.Session" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.identitytoolkit.demo-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
 (...)
 Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.facebook.Session
  (...)
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Here is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.google.identitytoolkit.demo"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.identitytoolkit.demo.GitkitDemo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="gitkit"
                       android:scheme="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="identitytoolkit.show_providers"
        android:value="Google, Yahoo, Facebook" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="identitytoolkit.use_google_plus"
        android:value="false" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="identitytoolkit.api_key"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="identitytoolkit.server_client_id"
        android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="identitytoolkit.server_widget_url"
        android:value="INSERT_YOUR_SERVER_WIDGET_URL" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_app_id"/>
</application>
```

GitkitDemo.java

```
package com.google.identitytoolkit.demo;

 import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.google.identitytoolkit.GitkitClient;
import com.google.identitytoolkit.GitkitUser;
import com.google.identitytoolkit.IdToken;

import java.io.IOException;

public class GitkitDemo extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private GitkitClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);


@Override
public void onSignIn(IdToken idToken, GitkitUser user) {
    showProfilePage(idToken, user);


  }
@Override
public void onSignInFailed() {
  Toast.makeText(GitkitDemo.this, "Sign in failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}).build();

showSignInPage();
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
if (!client.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent)) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}

}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
if (!client.handleIntent(intent)) {
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
 }
}
private void showSignInPage() {
 setContentView(R.layout.welcome);
 Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_in);
 button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void showProfilePage(IdToken idToken, GitkitUser user) {
setContentView(R.layout.profile);
showAccount(user);
findViewById(R.id.sign_out).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_in) {
  client.startSignIn();
 } else if (v.getId() == R.id.sign_out) {
  showSignInPage();
 }
}

private void showAccount(GitkitUser user) {
((TextView) findViewById(R.id.account_email)).setText(user.getEmail());

if (user.getDisplayName() != null) {
  ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.account_name)).setText(user.getDisplayName());
 }

if (user.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
  final ImageView pictureView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.account_picture);
  new AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>() {

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg) {
      try {
        byte[] result = HttpUtils.get(arg[0]);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(result, 0, result.length);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        return null;
      }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
      if (bitmap != null) {
        pictureView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
      }
    }
  }.execute(user.getPhotoUrl());
  }
 } 
 }
```

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
 }
}

repositories {
mavenCentral()
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
    }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
compile(name: 'identitytoolkit-api11', ext: 'aar')
compile(name: 'identitytoolkit_fb', ext: 'jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to Facebook changed its SDK for v4. Facebook Session Class is no longer there. This library 'identitytoolkit_fb' only works for Facebook Android SDK v3. I guess you probably would like to download the v4 version library from Github https://github.com/googlesamples/identity-toolkit-android/blob/master/plugins/identitytoolkit_fbv4.jar?raw=true.

Use that one to replace the current "identitytoolkit_fb.jar". That will work.

Comment: Hi, I am facing a similar issue. May I know where is "identitytoolkit_fb.jar" located and where do I replace it.